# Android Gradle - Can't use find classes of module's included lib

Tags: android, gradle

This project in compound of the 3 modules (app, datecs e volley). The `datecs` module is an interface between the library `libs/com.datecs.api.jar`. The issue is that the library classes/package isn't visible in the app module.

Here are the gradle files:

**project.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    implementation project(':volley')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    implementation project(':datecs')
}
```

**datecs.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/com.datecs.api.jar')
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

How can I make the library classes accessible in the app module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have access to your specific library (datecs), I tested with an app module and a library module where the app module needs to "import" the `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` dependency from the library module.

Using `api` instead of `implementation` did the trick for me.

Dependencies closure in build.gradle of the app module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(':mytestlibrary')
}
```

Dependencies closure in build.gradle of the library module:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

See also the documentation on [Dependency Configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations) for `api`:

> Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath and build output. When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile time.